# Collation mismatch between MariaDB and Java application

Tags: java, mariadb, comparator, collation

My application executes two separate queries to receive two independent lists of data, which are received by ordering them on several columns, the sortkey.

```
// Get input1 from the DB (sorted on input1.row.sortkey)
// Get Input2 from the DB (sorted on input2.row.sortkey)
// Get the first row from input1 => input1.row
// Get the first row from input2 => input2.row
// Loop until input1 and input2 have been exhausted.
//    Compare input1.row.sortkey with input2.row.sortkey
//    if input1.row.sortkey == input2.row.sortkey
//       update existing data
//    else if input1.row.sortkey > input2.row.sortkey
//       insert new data
//    else // thus input1.row.sortkey < input2.row.sortkey
//       deprecate old data
//    endif
//    Get the next row from input1
//    Get the next row from input2
```

Now a problem arises at this step:

```
Compare input1.row.sortkey with input2.row.sortkey
```

The sorting order of two keys in the database is done differently in the java code.

In MariaDB we use charset UTF8 (should have been UTF8mb4 but not possible to convert a.t.m.) with collation UTF8_general_ci as collation.

An example would be:

In the database a key like *0BSwN39hRWmg6goA0BGPDQ* is considered to preceed *0b_4GHGyQyKKyuXY-TBnwA* but for java this is vice versa.

How can this behaviour be aligned? Any solution will do. I have investigated the possibility of a RuleBasedCollator but that would require me to define the whole collation chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I just translated the _ character to Character.MAX_VALUE in java. This makes the comparison work for me, but this is only true because of the set of possible characters my sorting keys can have (a-zA-Z, 0-9, - and _). No guarantee this will work for other symbols or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a Comment)

Is `B` supposed to be less than `b`?  If so, you need `utf8_bin` collation.

Is `S` supposed to be less than '_'?  Any utf8 collation works.

But...

Your algorithm is (I think) incorrect... You should not get two new rows every time; cases 2 and 3 need to get a new input line from only one of the input streams.

Comment: Instead I just concluded that MariaDB sucks (same for MySQL), don't use it. Not only for this but never trust a DB that truncates data as default behaviour. "O the data doesn't fit the row, lets just throw it away. And while we are at it lets just mess up collations."

Comment: Join the group of users that clamor for "strict mode" being the default -- it is the default as of version 5.7.5:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html